# TypeError: hash must be unicode or bytes, not flask_sqlalchemy.BaseQuery

Tags: python, flask-sqlalchemy

```
def login():
if request.method=='POST':
    username=request.form['username']
    password_candidate=request.form['password']
    l_result=db.session.query(users).filter(users.username == username).all()
    if len(l_result) > 0:
        user=db.session.query(users.password).filter(users.username == username)
        if sha256_crypt.verify(password_candidate,user):
            app.logger.info('PASSWORD MATCHED')
        else:
            app.logger.info('PASSWORD MISMATCH')
    else:
        app.logger.info('NO USER')
return render_template('login.html')
```

I want to verify weather password_candidate and password from user are matched ..but it fails to verify..what can be the problem?

Comment: Please add the error traceback as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`sha256_crypt.verify`` accepts a plaintext password and a password hash as its arguments.

The code in the question is passing a sqlalchemy query instead of a hashed password.

```
user=db.session.query(users.password).filter(users.username == username)
    if sha256_crypt.verify(password_candidate, user):
```

Probably you want to pass a `User` instance's encrypted password attribute (the exact name depends on your User model):

```
user = db.session.query(users.password).filter(users.username == username).one()
    if sha256_crypt.verify(password_candidate, user.encrypted_password):
```